# Posting characters to server in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, post

I'm trying to post a string which includes characters like "+" and "&". I'm using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding` to encode the string .The "+" character is updated as white space in server and the characters after the "&" character is getting trimmed. Am I doing something wrong? What is the right way to do it? Any help is appreciated.

I found an answer and I'm posting it here

http://simonwoodside.com/weblog/2009/4/22/how_to_really_url_encode/

Comment: What do your logs (in the app: before escaping, after escaping and on the server at reception) say ?

Comment: Have you added the request header with key `Content-Type` and value `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: If you found an answer, post it as an answer down below, and not as an edit to your question.

Comment: @AlexReynolds:My reputation is below 100.hence I cant answer it before    8 hours completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer and I'm posting it here

http://simonwoodside.com/weblog/2009/4/22/how_to_really_url_encode/

You should do the following:

```
NSString * encodedString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
    NULL,
    (CFStringRef)unencodedString,
    NULL,
    (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
    kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
```